# Using plotly without online plotly account

Tags: python, charts, plotly

Is it possible to use the plotly library to create charts in python without having an online plotly account? I think the code is opensource https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py. I would like to know whether we can use this without an online account.

Comment: Yes it is possible using offline plotly library. You can also refer this tutorial: https://github.com/SayaliSonawane/Plotly_Offline_Python

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. The only purpose of having a `plotly` account is to host the graphs in your `plotly` account.

[`Plotly Offline`](https://plot.ly/python/offline/) allows you to create graphs offline and save them locally. Instead of saving the graphs to a server, your data and graphs will remain in your local system.

Comment: How to install this module plotly.offline? I've plotly installed but it doesn't have this "offline" module.

Answer (score 10):

You can work offline without having a plotly account.
The plotly version should be 1.9.x series or higher.

```
import numpy as np
from plotly import __version__
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot,iplot
print (__version__) # requires version >= 1.9.0

#Always run this the command before at the start of notebook
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.graph_objs as go

x=np.array([2,5,8,0,2,-8,4,3,1])
y=np.array([2,5,8,0,2,-8,4,3,1])


data = [go.Scatter(x=x,y=y)]
fig = go.Figure(data = data,layout = go.Layout(title='Offline Plotly Testing',width = 800,height = 500,
                                           xaxis = dict(title = 'X-axis'), yaxis = dict(title = 'Y-axis')))


plot(fig,show_link = False)
```

Your offline plotly library is setup.
Reference : [Plotly Offline Tutorial](https://plot.ly/python/offline/)

[This the offline graph that is created and you check the there is no online url because the graph is stored in local directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsjSb.jpg)

Comment: @Alex Check the update of the answer and it will create a local graph in html file as shown in the image

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

To use Plotly offline.

Answer (score 0):

The offline package is great for non-subscribed users but the figure quality is noticeably lower than the online version. This could be a problem if you want to save the figure and share with others.

Comment: Correction, since 3.2, offline mode supports export of high-quality images.