# How to plot all peaks using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I am using the `peakutils` `Python` package to detect peaks in my data (the second column of `estimated.csv` - found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Iv8dfU4fTUam00dkR3T3Q0clE) (click the link).

Here is my code to find the peaks:

```
#/usr/bin/python -tt

import pandas as pd
import peakutils

estimated_data = pd.read_csv("estimated.csv", header=None)
col2 = estimated_data[:][1] # Second column data
print(col2[:]) # Print all the rows
index = peakutils.indexes(col2, thres=0.4, min_dist=1000)
print(index)
```

The peak detection works perfectly fine. I wanted to plot all the detected peaks as it is in the following tutorial.

https://plot.ly/python/peak-finding/

But it seems that `plotly` doesn't seem to work offline. Is there a different way of doing it using `Python` packages like `matplotlib`?

Comment: I think you are aware that asking for libraries is off-topic?! In case you want to ask about plot.ly first read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745917/using-plotly-without-online-plotly-account) then reword you question. In case you want to ask about plotting with matplotlib alone, reword your question to ask about the problem you have using matplotlib. Decide for one specific way. If you want to explore both ways, ask two different questions.

Answer (score 4):

Plotting the peaks with matplotlib can be done by using a plot with markers. The data is indexed by the index found from the peakutils function.

```
import pandas as pd
import peakutils
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

estimated_data = pd.read_csv("data/estimated.csv", header=None)
col1 = estimated_data[:][0] # First column data
col2 = estimated_data[:][1] # Second column data

index = peakutils.indexes(col2, thres=0.4, min_dist=1000)

plt.plot(col1,col2, lw=0.4, alpha=0.4 )
plt.plot(col1[index],col2[index], marker="o", ls="", ms=3 )

plt.show()
```

[image]

In order to connect the peaks with a line (as asked for in the comments), on would simply leave out the `ls=""`,

```
plt.plot(col1[index],col2[index], marker="o", ms=3 )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This pretty much seems to be like an exponential smoothing. Is there a way to kind of connect those dots (peaks) and form a line?

Comment: How about if we want to save the peak coordinates (`x` and `y` of the two columns) to another file?

Comment: You can use `numpy.savetxt` to save a numpy array to a file.

Comment: I did `np.savetxt('peak_data.csv',
       np.vstack((col1,col2)).T,
       delimiter=',')` - but it saves all the data. If we take `index`, it will print the row numbers instead.

Comment: I don't see the problem. It saves the data you provide it with.

Comment: So you have to supply the array with the peaks.