# How to fix plotly offline error?

Tags: plotly

I followed [Using plotly without online plotly account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745917/using-plotly-without-online-plotly-account) and did the following code at the beginning of a notebook:

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.graph_objs import *
import cufflinks as cf
```

But I still have the error:

`PlotlyRequestError: Account limit reached: Your account is limited to creating 25 charts. To continue, you can override or delete existing charts or you can upgrade your account at: https://plot.ly/products/cloud`

How to correctly perform off-line plotly scatter?

Thanks

Comment: You should use `import plotly.offline as py` instead of `import plotly.plotly as py`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
```

instead of

```
import plotly.plotly as py
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no complete working code to debug, please refer the below sample code, you must be calling the `iplot` incorrectly.

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.graph_objs import *
import cufflinks as cf

data = [go.Bar(
            x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
            y=[20, 14, 23]
    )]

iplot(data, filename='basic-bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already found a solution, but importing plotly like this:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
# these two lines allow your code to show up in a notebook
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode()
```

And then calling iplot like this:

```
plotly.offline.iplot(...)
```

to plot your work might be the way to do it! Hope it helps :)